Emeditorの印刷で行末が切れてしまいます
印刷すると行末が切れてしまいます。解決方法をお教えくださいますでしょうか。
Textのプロパティ「印刷」や「ページ設定」でいろいろ設定を変えてみたのですが、うまくいきません。

プリンター ドライバの問題の可能性もあります。Windows の設定で既定のプリンターを変更し、さらに EmEditor の設定のプロパティの [印刷] ページで、[リセット] ボタンをクリックしてから、再度お試しください。

ありがとうございます。フォントを「MS P明朝」→「MS 明朝」に変更したらうまくいきました。プロポーショナルフォントのままプリンターをJUST PDF 5に変更し、[印刷]ページで[リセット]ボタンをクリックしても、依然として同じ現象となりました。
